# PostgreSQL UPSERT Trigger returning id

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, upsert

I've an `UPSERT` trigger on a table that may update instead of inserting while doing insert operation. I've function doing insert on that table and `returning id` However it doesn't return an id when it updates instead of inserting. I want to get the id in both cases.

Trigger Code

```
perform 1 from tera_subject 
where id = new.subject_id and owner = new.user_id;

if found then
   return null;
else
   select id into vote_id from tera_votes where 
  user_id = new.user_id and
  subject_id = new.subject_id;
   if not found then
  return new;
   else
      -- raise notice 'vote_id: % ; vote: %',vote_id,new.vote;
      if(tg_op = 'INSERT') then
          begin
          -- raise notice 'redirecting to update';
          update tera_votes
              set vote=new.vote
              WHERE id = vote_id;
          end;
      elsif(tg_op = 'UPDATE') then
          -- raise notice 'in update';
          return new;
      end if;
      -- raise notice 'end of trigger %',tg_op;
      return null;
   end if;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Updated with Trigger Code. functions are just INSERT query with `RETURNING id`

Comment: Doesn't looks like a full definition, `DESCRIBE` section missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll manage to have anything “returned” by the trigger.

What you're doing inside is:

- running update based on your conditions;
- suppressing the `INSERT` statement that fired the trigger.

This means, that `INSERT` is terminated in an easy way (without exception), but it also means that it's impossible to provide you any details, as trigger functions do not return any values.

If you need to have the ID of the UPSERT-ed item, consider using a function that will always return you the ID, like [this one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE).

Comment: I thing I couldn't understand is What `LOOP` is doing there in that function ? Its iterating over what ?

Comment: You don't need such a loop. The general idea of the function suits your needs. That loop is required to re-issue the statement in case statement fails with exception when parallel session had managed to INSERT matching row after `UPDATE` found no rows and right before `INSERT` in that function.

Comment: Anyway I've kept the loop But http://pastebin.com/mVQHEiye is givving me Syntax Error near `LOOP`

Comment: Could you show the whole function definition, starting from `CREATE` and up to the final `;`, please?

Comment: That is PL/pgSQL function, so you should use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` for definition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10911/discussion-between-vyegorov-and-neel-basu)

Comment: @vyegorov all the pastebins for this question are unavailable. Can you please put that as a solution ?